# Stata can't open file saved in local cloud storage folder on Mac

Tags: macos, cloud, stata, filepath, onedrive

I am using Stata on a Mac. I updated the OS to Monterey today. If I try to open a .dta file---that is saved on my local computer in a folder that syncs to OneDrive---from code in the Do File Editor/Command prompt (where I refer to the file using its full file path), it doesn't open. The error is r(601) - File ... cannot be found.

But if I click on it in Finder, it opens in Stata just fine. After I have done this, I can then open this file in Stata by running the exact same Stata code that didn't work before. Somehow it seems like Stata can't see the file/folder initially, but then it can. I am not sure if this has to do with the OneDrive file/folder permissions or something else.

If, in Stata, I change the directory to the correct directory using `cd` and then load the file (without referring to the path), it works. However, I would like to be able to refer to the file using the entire file path and not have to change the directory each time.

Interestingly, if I change the directory to the correct directory ***using `Change working directory` in the `File` drop down*** and then try to load the file using the file path, it also works. But if I do not do the drop down and write out the `cd` using code, and try accessing the file using the path it doesn't work!

Somehow Stata has to initially "see"/"access" the correct folder (in a very particular way) before being able to access it with the file path. Very strange. (Just to be clear, if I do not change the directory to the correct directory and then try to load the file using its file path, it doesn't work.)

I also tried creating a file using `texdoc init...` (in a folder that already exists, but that has not been used by Stata before) and get this error:

```
could not create directory .....
                 mkdir():   693  could not create directory
          texdoc_mkdir():     -  function returned error
           texdoc_init():     -  function returned error
                 <istmt>:     -  function returned error
```

I do not get this error if I instead use another folder in the same directory that I have previously used.

I think that the error I am encountering is the same or similar to this one (with no acceptable answer): https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/onedrive-folder-doesnt-exist/e6b97d47-3f6a-4863-bf68-d3a02832f2bb

Comment: When you run the code via the do-file editor, have you pointed Stata to the correct directory using `cd`?

Comment: @Cybernike I have not tried that. But the file path is correct because it works *after* I have opened the file through Finder.

Comment: @Cybernike, yes if I change the directory and try to load it directly (without referring to a file path), it works. I updated my question to this effect.